# Configurable method read from XML used in VB.NET on calling

Tags: xml, vb.net, sendkeys

I have a question regarding how can i use a method name configurable to be called.
E.g

1.I have a xml file with three elements looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <element attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="Send" />
</root>
```

2.I am using a List (i made a class with three elements and create an object type list of that class) to store the elements from the xml file.

3.Then using a For statement : For Each element As ClassList In GetList
i want to call the configurable method from the xml file instead  :

Theoratically instead of SendWait i want to have the value of attribute3(the value is SendWait) to be called.

instead of SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}") 
something like this:

```
SendKeys.element.Thirdelement()("{ENTER}")
```

- the value of element.Thirdelement() is  SendWait

I know that attribute3 could have 2 values : Send or Sendwait
Should i use a if statement, or is there any solution available?

```
If element.ThirdElement() = "SendWait" Then
                                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
                            Else
                                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

I am new in programming so please excuse me if one of the  statement above is an aberration!

LE:
I have a new class ListClass1 with three members and properties:

```
firstElement()
secondElement()
thirdElement()
```

I am using this class in order to store the data from xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
<element attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="Send" />
</root>
```

So after i add the values to the list, for example :  **element.ThirdElement()** will have the value from attribute3 ("Send"). 
Also **element.secondElement()** will retain the value from attribute2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to do the task. First Define a class holding your methods:

```
Public Class MethodsToExecute
    Public Sub Send(par1)
       SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") 
    End Sub
    Public Sub SendWait(par1)
       SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then create a Sub for handling:

```
Public Shared Sub ExecuteMethodByName(ObjectToInvoke As Object, MethodName As String, ParamArray Parameters() As Object) 
     Dim m As Reflection.MethodInfo = ObjectToInvoke.GetType.GetMethod(MethodName)
     m.Invoke(ObjectToInvoke, Parameters)
End Sub
```

and now execution

```
dim mte as new MethodsToExecute
```

iterate thorough xml file and do

```
 ExecuteMethodByName(mte,element.ThirdElement(), element.firsElement(),element.secondElement())
```

The problem is that solution is dependent on attribute order not by their names but with more extensive reflection usage you can handle it too.
[ParamArray Example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/123239/paramarray-example)

Is it understandable?

Comment: thanks for your answer but honestly i don't understand how to implement that in my case...i have this phrase  = SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}" and need to have SendKeys.element.Thirdelement()("{ENTER}")

Comment: I have made some edit. But I probably don't understand your code. What is ThirdElement? Can you add a bit more code?

Comment: I hope I am using elements corectly. I suppose that they contain attributes values).